# Prepopulate memory database when running client tests with Arquillian

Tags: ejb, h2, jboss-arquillian

I have the following requirement:

I want to test my UI (using graphene and drone) but I need to login to the application before all tests. I have a Database authentication Realm in jboss which for testing uses an H2 in-memory database. So what I need is to add a user (username, password) before all tests in the users table so I can login successfully in my application.

I first tried to inject my users EJB in the test class so I can create a user before all tests in the database. This is impossible because the UI tests run on the client (testable=false). It was obvious that at the time I did not know exactly how arquillian works...

I then tried to use arquillian persistence extension and @UsingDataSet annotation but this also fails for the same reason (although I am not sure why, since I don't know exactly how this annotation works).

Finally, I tried to create a Singleton EJB with @Startup annotation and on its @PostConstruct method create the user I need. When debugging, I can see in the H2 console that the user is created. But when I run my tests the login still fails.

Can someone explain why this last case fails because I do not understand. But most importently if someone knows how to make this work I would greately appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

So, when you run a client side test nothing gets added to your archive.  If it's possible for you, mark your archive as `testable=true` and then these extensions will be added to the test.  Your can do things like have a setup method that runs on the server, however the values for the user will not be sent you.  You'll need to insert them.  As long as you're ok with that need this should work for you.